# How to Pass and return Array of properties in jni (java to c++) as well as (c++ to java)

Tags: java-native-interface

How to Pass and return  **Array of properties** in **jni** (java to c++) as well as (c++ to java)

```
import java.util.*; 


public class Test { 
    public native static Properties[] getStudentDetails();   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary("Sample");
        int a= 10;
        Properties[] records = getStudentDetails();      
        for(Properties record:records){
            System.out.print("\ntype:"+record.getProperty("type"));
            System.out.print("\ttime:"+record.getProperty("time"));
            System.out.print("\tsource:"+record.getProperty("source"));
            System.out.print("\teid:"+record.getProperty("eid"));
            System.out.println("");
        }

    }   
}
```

it give me error

Comment: What error do you get? What does your JNI implementation look like?

Comment: Also, any specific reason you code a `Properties` object over a custom Java class?

Comment: i  send a struct object  from c++ and using java class object it worked but if i change it to array of properties it is not working

Comment: i just want to display windows event log using jni especially using Properties

Comment: Okay. Show your actual JNI code so we can tell you what to fix.

Comment: i am not able to send a complete code

Comment: i try to split and send

Comment: #include<map>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include "com_test_Test.h"
 
 
typedef struct _JNI_POSREC {
    jclass cls;
    jmethodID constructortorID;
    jfieldID typeID;
    jfieldID timeID;
    jfieldID sourceID;
    jfieldID eidID;
} JNI_POSREC;

Comment: void FillStudentRecordDetails(std::vector<SearchRecord*>* searchRecordResult ){
    SearchRecord *pRecord1 = new SearchRecord();
    pRecord1->type = "type1";
    pRecord1->time = "time1";
    pRecord1->source = "source1";
    pRecord1->eid = "eid1";
    
    searchRecordResult->push_back(pRecord1);

Comment: SearchRecord *pRecord2 = new SearchRecord();
    pRecord2->type = "type2";
    pRecord2->time = "time2";
    pRecord2->source = "source2";
    pRecord2->eid = "eid2";
    searchRecordResult->push_back(pRecord2);
 
}

Comment: https://cppcodetips.wordpress.com/2014/02/25/returning-array-of-user-defined-objects-in-jni/

Comment: the above like is my referance same only i done

Comment: NO! Edit your question instead.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have access to a `std::vector<SearchRecord*> searchRecordResult` somewhere:

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_Test_getStudentDetails(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls) {
    // Get Properties class, its constructor and the put method
    jclass cls_Properties = env->FindClass("java/util/Properties");
    jmethodID mid_Properties_ctor = env->GetMethodID(cls_Properties, "<init>", "()V");
    jmethodID mid_Properties_put = env->GetMethodID(cls_Properties, "put", "(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;");

    // Construct the key Strings up front
    jstring key_type = env->NewStringUTF("type");
    jstring key_time = env->NewStringUTF("time");
    jstring key_source = env->NewStringUTF("source");
    jstring key_eid = env->NewStringUTF("eid");

    jobjectArray ret = env->NewObjectArray(searchRecordResult.size(), cls_Properties, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < searchRecordResult.size(); i++) {
        auto result = searchRecordResult[i];
        // Allocate and fill a Properties object, making sure to clean up the value Strings.
        env->PushLocalFrame(5);
        jobject prop = env->NewObject(cls_Properties, mid_Properties_ctor);
        env->CallObjectMethod(prop, mid_Properties_put, key_type, env->NewStringUTF(result->type));
        env->CallObjectMethod(prop, mid_Properties_put, key_time, env->NewStringUTF(result->time));
        env->CallObjectMethod(prop, mid_Properties_put, key_source, env->NewStringUTF(result->source));
        env->CallObjectMethod(prop, mid_Properties_put, key_eid, env->NewStringUTF(result->eid));
        prop = env->PopLocalFrame(prop);
        env->SetObjectArrayElement(ret, i, prop);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

The core loop just constructs `Properties` objects, fills their properties with `put` and assigns them to the right slot on the `ret` array.

Comment: if i use array of properties my java code say cannot invoke with array of properties

Comment: error: 'result' does not name a type
         auto result = searchRecordResult[i];
              ^
event.cpp:161:85: error: 'result' was not declared in this scope
         env->CallObjectMethod(prop, mid_Properties_put, key_type, env->NewStringUTF(result->type));

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60426822/how-to-display-a-windows-event-log-details-in-jni-the-return-data-must-be-array

Comment: jclass cls_Properties = env->FindClass("java/util/Properties");

Comment: after the jclass declaration line the program not equating in jni